# How to allow users to click on a button while keeping the sheet read-only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

**context**

I'm currently trying to setup a quick registration form with google-sheet and google-form (with the help of google-apps-script).

We are organising exams sessions at our university. For each exam, there is a need for proctoring.

- I want people who are available for proctoring to register via a Google Form. The registration is based on a first-in first-served basis. Therefore, the Google Form cannot display all the sessions all the time (otherwise, people may *over*-register some sessions and other sessions will be left empty).
- I also want people to see the list of sessions so they can see

  - the date and time of the session
  - see if there is a need for a lot of people

**Current implementation**
I do have a list of sessions (with the details) and a button (register) underneath it:
[image: current worksheet].

This spreadsheet calculates the number of Teaching Assistants required based on its' content and the answers to the Google form.

When people click on "Register" an apps-script is run that re-calculates the options of a question (to what session do you want to register?) and displays the Form.

**current painpoint**
Obviously, I don't want Teaching Assistants to be able to modify the spreadsheet. Therefore, I am sending them a 'read-only' link. Unfortunately, the 'Register' button cannot be clicked.

**Question**

Is there a way that I can keep the spreadsheet 'read-only' while allowing to click on the *button*?

Comment: Can you put a button on the side bar?

Comment: @Cooper It works with my account. Now, I need to test with someone who does not have access...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Instead of providing `read-only` access, you can use [sheet protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)

This allows you to disable unwanted editors from editing the sheet contents, but they will still be able to run a script.